# How to list in django all users profiles registered in the frontend?

Tags: python, django

This is my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', enter code hereupload_to='profile_pics')
```

This is my views.py, in my template profile.html iam trying to list in a for loop but with no sucess

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Conta criada com sucesso para! Agora é possivel efectuar o login')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form}

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, 
                                request.FILES, 
                                instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Conta actualizada com sucesso!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
        "title": "profile"
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

template is in the users app profile.html

Comment: Please provide the template code.

Comment: Have you tried using `Profile.objects.all()` ?

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami thnx man! it was all that i need, i forgot to insert that code :D